# Matlab skipping plots (uncertainty)

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a sequence of finding fits for data (cd to folder, read and fit the data) and subsequently plotting them in a loop.

I observe that few plots are done incorrectly, skipped and added in subsequent plots. A four second `pause` between each plots seems to solve this issue.

I assume everything is sequential in Matlab, meaning subsequent commands wait until current command is finished. I believe this is not the way happening now. I believe using `pause` is not the best solution. Can someone provide a fix for this?

A set of subsequent plots without the pause (solid line is a fit of datapoints on the fly):

[image]
[image]

The same plots with pause of 4 seconds:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`subplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html), and most other functions that generate graphics objects, [provide a handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html#btw1t4b-1-ax) to the generated graphics object that you can use to address the object [explicitly](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#btzitot-ax) with functions like [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html).

If an explicit axis handle is not provided to a plotting function, it will use the [current axes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gca.html), which can very often lead to issues like these. So much so that it's caveated in the documentation:

> User interaction can change the current axes or chart. It is better to assign the axes or chart to a variable when you create it instead of relying on `gca`.

So rather than doing:

```
axes
plot(1:10)
```

You should do the following:

```
ax = axes;
plot(ax, 1:10)
```